# return- and return! in C

Tags: c

While looking through puzzles and answers in the code golf Q&A section, I came across [this solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12201) for the longest and most obscure ways to return 1

Quoting from the answer,

```
int foo(void) {
    return! 0;
}

int bar(void) {
    int i=7;
    while (i --> 0);
    return-i;
}
```

The --> 'operator' is already well-known :), but I couldn't find any info on `return! 0;` and `return-x;` where I'm guessing `x` could be any variable

Do they really exist, and what do they mean? Does it have anything to do with precedence?

Comment: There is no --> operator.  It is (i--) > 0.  They're just trying to be obscure by playing with the spacing.  return! 0 is return (!0).  return-i is return (-i)

Comment: Just insert some spaces here and there. This has nothing to do with precedence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `!` and `-` are for the "second part of the operator", they don't have anything to do with `return`.

`return-x;` just `return`s the negated value of `x`.

`return! 0;` is `return (!0);`, nothing special.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Became worried with the prospect of 'return' precedence, even though return is a statement :p

Answer (score 4):

It's really the same idea as with `-->`.  C compilers *tokenize* program text using a [particular algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch) that makes

```
return-i
```

parse like

```
return -i
```

and

```
return! 0
```

parse like

```
return !0
```

All the same.

Answer (score 0):

The notation `return! 0` can be interpreted as `return (!0)` which is basically `return 1`.

The other notation `return -x` where `x` is equal to `-1` (as a result of `while (x --> 0);` is just `return 1`.

Answer (score 0):

`return!0;` is the same as `return (!0);`, and `!0 == 1`.

For second one, `return-i` returns `1` because `i==-1` at that point (after `while` loop decrements it to -1), and `return-i` same as `return (-i)`, or `return 1`.

Comment: its it -(-1)  ie 1..? Did you mean i=-1 than i==-1?

Comment: @Digital_Reality I think mvp was just saying == in explanation that the value of i is -1, not as in the code is performing a comparison of i==-1

Answer (score 0):

The spacing may be throwing you off:

```
return !0;
```

is basically making 0 non-0, or "true", 1.

"-->" is not "an" operator, it is 2 operators: decrement&save-later "--" and compare ">"

i-- > 0, or see if i is still greater than 0 then decrement it.  What it's usage is doing is decrementing i from 7 until it becomes 0 (and decrements after the compare making a negative number, which the first occurrence would be -1)

```
return -i;
```

is just turning that -1 into a positive 1